# Rails Cassandra DB Error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, cassandra

I'm trying to create a new record after migrating my database in cassandra. However I'm getting an error and I'm not sure how what it means. I had no luck on Google.

`Ione::Io::ConnectionClosedError: Not enough bytes available to decode a` `string: 2560 bytes required but only 101 available`
`from /home/blau08/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cql-rb-2.0.4/lib/cql/client/connector.rb:30:in block in connect_all'`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a defect in your version of the driver. I see that you're using cql-rb. DataStax took over maintenance of this driver over a year ago, and we've fixed these sorts of issues in v3.0.x, so please try that out. The gem is named 'cassandra-driver' and is available from RubyGems.

Comment: I think it might be my cassandra. I tried bundling cassandra-driver and it still doesn't work. My sudo service cassandra status is active (exited). So I think that's the problem.

Comment: Try connecting with cqlsh and running some trivial queries. If that doesn't work, you definitely have an issue on the C* node side that you need to resolve first. Also, look for error messages in the C* logs.